# Injecting a bean inside another bean and use it in the constructor?

Tags: spring, constructor, dependency-injection, managed-bean

I have a bean that looks like this:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class AlarmChartSettingsBean implements Serializable {
...
```

Inside this bean i inject another bean like this:

```
@Inject
private SessionInfoBean sessionInfoBean;
```

Then i call the injected bean inside the constructor of the first bean like this:

```
public AlarmChartSettingsBean() {

    String atcaIp = sessionInfoBean.getNwConfigBean().getAtcaIP();
}
```

The problem is that the injected bean is null. So the question is when is that bean injected? Can i use it inside the constructor or i should use it after the bean has been constructed?

Comment: You can only inject a bean into a bean when there is an instance. So it isn't available in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor of a Spring bean is called before Spring has any chance to autowire any fields. This explains why `sessionInfoBean` is `null` inside the constructor.

If you want to initialize a Spring bean, you can:

- annotate a method with [`@PostConstruct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html):

  ```
  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
      String atcaIp = sessionInfoBean.getNwConfigBean().getAtcaIP();
  }
  ```
- implement [`InitializingBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) and write the initialization code inside the `afterPropertiesSet` method:

  ```
  public class AlarmChartSettingsBean implements Serializable, InitializingBean {

      @Override
      void afterPropertiesSet() {
          String atcaIp = sessionInfoBean.getNwConfigBean().getAtcaIP();
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: AFAIK you may autowire the constructor too.

Comment: @PeterRader Yes it is possible. There are a lot of possible solutions, it would take forever to list them all

Answer (score 1):

The `@Inject` on a Field will autowire after the constructor has been called.

Note: In some Spring-Apps the `@Inject` may not work, use `@Autowire` instead.